# How should I deploy VS project/item templates?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, vsx, vs-extensibility

I made an installer for project and item templates in VS2010 to put the templates in the user's `Templates` folder. Is this an OK way of doing things? Or is there a way to deploy templates for all users? If so - where should I put them?

Comment: If you are targeting Visual Studio 2010 only, you should check out this post on the Visual Studio Blog that walks you through creating and installing templates via a VSIX file. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/04/creating-and-sharing-project-item-templates.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If all of the developers can access a common location, you can put your templates there and set the 'User project templates location' and 'User item templates location' properties in VS Options/Projects and Solutions/General

Comment: No this is something intended for distribution.